# On iOS, left flex-Item collapses when many inline elems on the right. Workaround?

Tags: html, ios, css, flexbox

I noticed that when there are many inline elements in the right flex-item, the left flex-item is somehow collapsed, on iOS (or iPad. I don't have an iPhone):

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
    <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
    Wanna Stay Center n Don't Push Me.    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Push!!</span>
    <span>Push!!</span>
    <span>Push!!</span>
    <span>Push!!</span>
    <span>Push!!</span>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jpLo0ava/2/

I realized that this happens on both of Chrome and Safari. Is this a brower bug or is there any wrong css usage? How should I handle this if I want to make the left text stay vertically in the middle?

Comment: Tested in iPad Safari, and layout working fine. Left item not collapsing; stays vertically centered.

Comment: @Michael_B Really? After a day, I'm still struggling with this issue...

Answer (score 0):

All right, setting `flex-shrink: 0;` on the left worked for me...